# WebDeploy from TeamBuild fails with http 504

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a simple VS2012 mvc website. I have built a deployment package for this to deploy to the local instance of IIS 8. I am able to publish this manually from Visual Studio (right click the project and hit publish) and it works great.

I created a TFS 2012 build for the project. This successfully compiled and executed my unit tests. My next step was to enhance the build so that it also deployed the website - this is where I've run into problems.

I added the following as "MSBuild Arguments": /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/TrainingCompany" /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=urlhere.com /p:username=username /p:password=password

Following a build I get the following in the msbuild log file:

```
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://urlhere.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site'.
The operation has timed out
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.PerformHeadRequestHelper(Boolean getVersionInfo, Version& maximumSupportedVersion, Version& minimumSupportedVersion)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String serverVersion)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateDestinationObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeployObject.SyncTo(VSMSDeployObject destObject, Object syncOptions, IVSMSDeployHost _host)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[T0,T1,T2,T3](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.BaseMSDeployDriver.InvokeMSdeploySync()
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.BaseMSDeployDriver.SyncThruMSDeploy()
at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.VSMSDeploy.Execute()
```

From fiddler I've tried executing the following as a GET request - my guess is I should get something back but I just get a 504 timeout:

http://urlhere.com:8172/msdeploy.axd

Could anyone please advise what I may be doing wrong or what extra steps I can take to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to WebDeploy being set up on HTTPS by default, not HTTP.

Try https://urlhere.com:8172/msdeploy.axd and see how you go.